# Localized Url : Vue3 + vite + vite-plugin-vue-i18n

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, vue-i18n, vite

I'm trying to get some localized url for my current project. So far I made a Lang dropdown that save the language in local storage for the next access to the website, Translations are imported from .json (with the help of vite-plugin-vue-i18n) files and work. So the translation is working  The route that is commented work but when I introduce a Lang variable. I get: TypeError: guard.call is not a function. Any idea ?

Router.js

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";

import Home from '../pages/Home.vue'
import About from '../pages/About.vue'
import i18n from '../locales/i18n'

/*const routes = [

    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        component: About,
    }

]*/

let locale = 'en'

if(localStorage.getItem('lang')) {
    locale = localStorage.getItem('lang')
}

i18n.locale = locale;

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: `/${i18n.locale}`
    },
    {
        path: `/${i18n.locale}`,
        component: {
            beforeRouteEnter: `/${i18n.locale}`,
            beforeRouteUpdate: `/${i18n.locale}`,
            render(h) { return h('router-view'); }
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                name: 'home',
                component: Home,
            },
            {
                path: 'about',
                name: 'about',
                component: About,
            }
        ]
    }
]


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
})

export default router;
```